# Should I put "entry level" on my resume?

Tags: career-development

So I'm finding pretty quickly that competition is extremely stiff for entry level web developers (we have the world as our competition, after all). Should I even bother putting "entry level" on my resume? Will that get my 2 pages tossed out? I'm at a bit of a wit's end since I'm running out of money and I have loans to pay back.

Other relevant information: I'm currently putting ~6 hours a day into self learning. So I guess I would appreciate an answer to the main question but if any higher level devs have advice, please provide...

Comment: Do you have any relevant work experience? Self Training is great, but relevant work experience or a project you can show will have way more value.

Comment: I would think Junior would look better on a resume versus entry level, but that is my opinion.

Comment: Ah yes. My apologies, that would have been great information. I am entry level. However, I have a 4 year degree from a fairly prodigious state school (University of New Hampshire), 3 years of experience with technical support, and 6 months of experience with Web Development. No coding bootcamps here (apologies if I offend anyone's sensitivities but I have not heard anything good about them).

Answer (score 5):

No, I doubt adding it would help much.

The positions you're applying for should tell them what you're looking for and your experience should tell them what you're qualified for.

If you're applying for an entry-level position, stating this on your resume doesn't add any information. If you're applying for a more senior position, your resume is likely to get thrown out either way - if they happen to have an entry-level position, whether they consider you for that is unlikely to be influenced by you adding "entry-level" to your resume.

If you *are* applying for a senior position (or sending your resume with no specific role in mind) in hopes that they have a junior position available, your cover letter or email would be a better place to try to convey this information or enquire about this.

---

You can get pretty experienced (way past entry-level) in software development by working on personal or open-source projects, taking online courses and/or freelancing.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Only problem is, it seems like companies don't really tend to "look" for junior level developers. if they do, it's the old mantra of "3 years' experience, knowledge in 8 different languages". Same stuff you find in engineering :)

Answer (score 3):

> Should I put “entry level” on my resume?

I would use the word **Junior** versus *entry level*.  That along with the other relevant information in your comment will give you the best shot at obtaining an interview.

As I mentioned in my comments, you can help yourself out a bit by making your work available for a potential employer to review via a website or GIT.

Breaking into software development is tough.  In the US, most jobs I see are for Senior level developers.  Be patient, as it might take some time to find the right position.

Comment: Thank you for the encouragement :) I do appreciate it. I'm working hard to break in, and will keep on trying.

Comment: Word **Junior** is exactly the right word.